# Replace commas except those in quotation marks

Tags: python, replace, readfile

```
Date,Time,Ref,Sen,ATN,Flow,PCB temp,Status,Battery,BC
2015/04/23,12:30:00,779581,908043,"-15,254",49,31,0,100,
2015/04/23,12:35:00,778715,907084,"-15,259",49,31,0,100,-127
2015/04/23,12:40:00,778299,906419,"-15,239",49,32,0,100,461
(...)
```

Hi, I have an ascii file like the one above where I am trying to replace the commas for semicolon. This is the code I am using:

```
filein = open('Prueba1.txt')
fileout = open('Fin.txt', 'wt')
for line in filein:
    if line.startswith('20'):
        fileout.write( line.replace(',', ';') )
filein.close()
fileout.close()
```

The problem is that now I want to maintain the commas for the 5th column and also take of the quotation marks.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered saving this as a csv file.

after saving it as csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
v = pd.read_csv("check_delete.csv")
```

output:

```
      Date            Time  Ref     Sen      ATN      Flow  PCB temp    Status  Battery BC
0   2015/04/23  12:30:00    779581  908043  -15,254 49  31  0   100   NaN
1   2015/04/23  12:35:00    778715  907084  -15,259 49  31  0   100   -127.0
2   2015/04/23  12:40:00    778299  906419  -15,239 49  32  0   100    461.0
```

You can read this as a dataframe.

Comment: `v.to_csv('new.csv',sep=';',index=False)` will save it as a new csv file with `;` as the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This panda library is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer making use of the `split()` method if you do not want to use .csv files.

Let's consider the line to be:

`line = '2015/04/23,12:35:00,778715,907084,"-15,259",49,31,0,100,-127'`

First, split the line into three parts. One before the part in the quotes, the quoted part, and the part after the part in quotes.
This can be done by `line.split('"')`.

This will give us a list consisting of these three parts:

`alist = ['2015/04/23,12:35:00,778715,907084,', '-15,259', ',49,31,0,100,-127']`

Now, split the first and last elements of the list by the comma.
And add all the elements to an empty string.
Write this string to your new file.

Like this:

```
left_part = alist[0].split(',')
right_part = alist[2].split(',')
middle_part = alist[1]
final_list = left_part + [middle_part] + right_part
new_line = ''
for part in final_list:
    # to prevent the empty strings to be added add the if condition.
    if part:
        new_line += part + ';'
```

The final result should look like this:

`'2015/04/23;12:35:00;778715;907084;-15,259;49;31;0;100;-127;'`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) Python standard library:

```
import csv

with open('example.csv', newline='') as inputfile, \
     open('parsedcsv.csv', 'w',  newline='') as outpufile:

    datareader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    csvwriter = csv.writer(outpufile, delimiter=';',
            quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    csvwriter.writerows(datareader)
```

Quote from the documentation about the [QUOTE_MINIMAL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) option:

> csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL: Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields
>   which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any
>   of the characters in lineterminator.

The output file is:

```
Date;Time;Ref;Sen;ATN;Flow;PCB temp;Status;Battery;BC
2015/04/23;12:30:00;779581;908043;-15,254;49;31;0;130;
2015/04/23;12:35:00;778715;907084;-15,259;49;31;0;100;-127
2015/04/23;12:40:00;778299;906419;-15,239;49;32;0;100;461
```