# select specific lines with specific condition from a large text file with python

Tags: python, text, jupyter-notebook, linecache

I have a text file which has 5 columns and more than 2 million lines as follows,

```
134   1   2   6    3.45388e-06
135   1   2   7    3.04626e-06
136   1   2   8    4.69364e-06
137   1   2   9    4.21627e-06
138   1   2   10   2.38822e-06
139   1   2   11   1.91216e-06
...
140   1   3   2    5.23876e-06
141   1   3   3    2.83415e-06
142   1   3   7    2.32097e-06
143   1   3   9    6.26283e-06
144   1   3   16   4.22556e-06
...  
145   2   1   2   3.67182e-06
146   2   1   4   4.61481e-06
147   2   1   6   1.1703e-06
...
148   2   2   7   4.61242e-06
149   2   2   21   1.84259e-06
150   2   2   22   4.31435e-06
...
151   2   3   23   4.34518e-06
152   2   3   24   3.76576e-06
153   2   3   25   2.61061e-06
...
154   3   1   2   4.07107e-06
155   3   1   7   4.83971e-06
156   3   1   8   3.43919e-06
...
157   3   2   29   6.27991e-06
158   3   2   30   7.44213e-06
159   3   2   31   9.56985e-06
...
160   3   3   32   1.38377e-05
161   3   3   33   1.62724e-05
162   3   3   34   9.85653e-06
...
```

Second column shows the number of each layer and in each layer I have a matrix which columns 3 and 4 are numbers of row and columns in that layer and the last column is my data
 First I want to put a condition that if second column is equal to a number (for example 3), print all the lines of this condition in another file, and I am doing that with this code:

```
    with open ('C:\ Python \ projects\A.txt') as f,  open('D:\ Python \New_ projects\NEW.txt', 'w') as f2:
      # read the data from layer 120 and write these data in New.txt file
      for f in islice (f,393084, 409467):
        f2.write(f)
a = np.loadtxt('D:\ Python \New_ projects\NEW.txt
```

But the problem is that for each layer I have to go to the file and find the first and last number of lines for each layer and put it in islice , which takes so long because the file is so big
What can I do that I just say  for column[2] = 4    save the lines in New text??

***** and After that I need another condition that for Column[2] = 4 ,    if     20 <=column[3] <= 50 and
 80 <=column[4] <= 120    -->  save these lines in another file..

Comment: Read 'A.txt' into a list and work on it: datalist=f.readlines()

Answer (score 0):

use grep function and create another file with filtered data, grep is fast enough to work on files

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) could be a fast non-python solution, using regex, for example:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+2\s' testgrep.txt > output.txt
```

which save in the file `output.txt` all the lines with a `2` on the third column. See https://regex101.com/r/j5EfEE/1 for the details about the pattern.

Comment: Tnx, it sounds good,and I think I can use that, but I need to do in python, too, because this is a part of my code and I need to use this file afterwards in python, and even I do not know that it is possible to put a condition for example (  for 20 <=column[3] <= 50 print in output.txt ) using grep or not??

Comment: I edited the question to make it more to the point... One way to do this in Python is use the `csv` module for example in a similar way of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755998/8069403) i.e. reading the file line by line, and writing the filtered line on another file, I am not sure I would be efficient for large file, but the best is to make it work first with a relatively small file... Could you try to add in your question an attempt using `csv`?

Comment: Tnx, but I solve my problem using Panda, it was very simple and you can filter data in each column...